# Gstream video stream error

Tags: 14.04, video, webcam, gstreamer

I'm trying to stream webcam video from one computer to another with low or zero latency.
I used the following command.
Sender:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src !  video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 !  x264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay !  udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

But I get the following error :

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: This isn't a device '/dev/video0'.
Additional debug info:
v4l2_calls.c(575): gst_v4l2_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
system error: Success
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Does anybody have any idea how I can remove this error?

Comment: Does your webcam work in guvcview?

Answer (score 1):

The error means that /dev/video0 is not a video capture device. Perhaps you need to set another device using:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device="/dev/videoX" ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 !  x264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay !  udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

Where 'X' is the number of your video capture device. It might also happen that your device can't capture in 640x480 so you might want to add a videoscale before the  caps and also it is safe to have a videoconvert before the encoder in case the input is in a format that the encoder can't handle.

So something like:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=<device> ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay !  udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```